# How to configure Glassfish Server in Eclipse manually

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, configuration, glassfish

I have GlassFish server3.1.2.2 pre installed on my machine. Which I want to use in my Eclipse Luna

How do I manually configure it to use in Eclipse?

When I tried using Eclipse Market Place i got an error
**No repository found at http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/luna.**

I tried searching through net for which I get pointed to the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) which is of about 485MB.

Is there an another way round for this?

Comment: it's now at 732MB o_O

Comment: fyi as of 2/14/18 eclipse oxygen still will only support versions of GlassFish 3 and 4, so don't bother downloading 5 yet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You must use **Eclipse WTP** (*Web Tool Platform*), and should use the lastest version is Luna 4.4. 
Link download: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar

Menu **Windows\Show view\Other**, choose folder **Server**, click on **Servers**.
[image]
[image]
Right click on blank area to use context menu, choose **New\Server**
[image]

Press link "**Download additional server adapters**"
[image]

Choose "**GlassFish Tools**" from Oracle vendor. 
[image]
Then, restart Eclipse.

- Or you download **GlassFish tools** (Supports GlassFish 4.0 and **3.1**) from: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools and install manually.
- Read more about creating a server: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrtins.html

Comment: Help. I am using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with WTP, and it do not have GlassFish as an option there. Here is the link: http://prntscr.com/5gfp9n (I dont have it at the top either)

Comment: You should download GlassFish tools (Supports GlassFish 4.0 and 3.1) from: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna and **install manually**.

Comment: this is why eclipse is so terrible, and i have switched to netbeans. Its a configuration clusterf*&$§ck

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/luna try in install new software and select Glassfish tools from Tools.

Comment: I am not able to see the GlassFish tools option in the populated list. And the link that is mentioned here is broken

Answer (score 22):

I could fix it using below steps.(GlassFish server3.1.2.2 and eclipse Luna 4.4.1)

1. Help > Eclipse Marketplace > Search GlassFish > you will see
   GlassFish Tools > Select appropriate one and install it.
2. Restart eclipse
3. Windows > Open Views > Other > Server > Servers > GlassFish 3.1
4. You will need jdk1.7.0 added to Installed JRE. Close the previous window to take effect of new default jdk1.7.0.

Answer (score 15):

This questions seems a little bit outdated but here is my solution.

I assume that you have already downloaded GlassFish on your hard drive and unzipped the files on a directory.

#### A - Eclipse MarketPlace / Installing GlassFish Tools

The first thing as it is said on previous answers, you have to downloaded **GlassFish Tools** from **eclipse marketplace**;

**Help -> EclipseMarket Place**

[image]

And install GlassFish on the screen below;

[image]

#### B - Adding GlassFish Server

Open Server View, if it is not visible on the bottom of the eclipse, then;

**Window -> Show View -> Servers**

[image]

As the server view is visible, simply click "**No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server...**" as shown below;

[image]

#### C - Adding GlassFish Server

On the **New Server** window, select **GlassFish** as shown below. On my experience, there is **only one GlassFish option** that I can select, instead of several GlassFish options with versions as you can see down below;

[image]

#### D - Configuring GlassFish & Java Locations

Enter the exact GlassFish location and also Java location as you can see below;

[image]

#### E - Last Step

On the last step of this configuration, just leave everything as it is. For simplicity, I don't define an admin password;

[image]

Now everything is all set, hope that this helps!

Answer (score 8):

To use Glassfish tools with Eclipse Luna you need **Java 8**. I also faced this problem because I had Java 7. If you have Java 7 in your environment then download eclipse Kepler. It will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
Not able to install neither using **Marketplace** nor **Servers tab**.

Following is the alternative.

1) Help -> Install New Software

2) Use url : http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.6/luna/repository
   Above is the OEPE tool provided by oracle for EE development.

3) From all the suggestions, select glassfish tools.

4) Install it.

5) Restart eclipse.

Eclipse 4.4.2 Luna
JDK : 1.8

Comment: Updating the info, the URL you mention does not work any longer with STS 4.1.0.RELEASE , instead i recommend you to use [the updated URL.](http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to resolve it, go windows -> preferences -> servers and select runtime environment, and now you will see a new window, in the 
upper right you will see a option: Download additional server adapter, click and install the glassfish server.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Mars use the similar approach as harshit.

1) Help -> Install New Software
2) Use url: http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/mars repository Above is the OEPE tool provided by oracle for EE development.
3) From all the suggestions, select Glassfish Tools, (Oracle Weblogic Server Tools, Oracle Weblogic Scripting Tools, Oracle patches, Oracle Maven Tools).
4) Install it.
5) Restart eclipse

In point 3) are 4 tools are in braces, I don't know minimal combination, but only install Glassfish Tools has no effect.

During restart Oepe ask for Java 8 JDK if Eclipse run on on older version.

Eclipse 4.5.0 Mars JDK : 1.8

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Luna

Go to Help>Eclipse MarketPlace> Search for GlassFish Tools and install it.

Restart Eclipse.

Now go to servers>new>server and you will find Glassfish server.

Answer (score 0):

You should use eclipse official website and official oracle links.
https://www.eclipse.org/setups/marketplace/?id=2318313
http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/neon

Use the relevant link for the  new version eclipse .

It took me 4 hours to resolve this. Hope this helps others.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).