# Installing Glassfish tools in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, glassfish, eclipse-luna

Im trying to install Glassfish tools in eclise Luna but I keep getting this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: GlassFish Tools 7.3.3.201412231459 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 7.3.3.201412231459)
Missing requirement: GlassFish Tools 7.3.3.201412231459 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 7.3.3.201412231459) requires 'org.eclipse.sapphire.feature.group [8.1.0,8.2.0)' but it could not be found
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like they somehow messed up the plugin dependencies while packaging the plugin version which is currently referenced by the .

To fix it you have to install an slightly older version of the Glassfish Tools manually. To do this in Eclipse click on `Help` -> `Install new software` and put the following URL in the upper input field:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.1/luna/repository

Then click enter, after it has fetched the installable packages, choose the `Glassfish Tools` package and the `Oracle Java EE Tools` package (both should be version 7.2.0.xxx) and install. The installation can take a while because the oracle repository site is often slow.

**See also:**

- [How to configure Glassfish Server in Eclipse Luna manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25200410/how-to-configure-glassfish-server-in-eclipse-luna-manually)
- [Define a New Server choosing GlassFish 3.1 gives Internal Error - Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157539/define-a-new-server-choosing-glassfish-3-1-gives-internal-error-eclipse-luna)

Comment: Thanks for this. This is one of the reasons why I'm thinking of moving to Netbeans.

Comment: After searching around, finally this one works. Thanks.

Comment: me too. Stuff like this makes me want to switch to netbeans too

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot :) You also can add that eclipse must be running with java 1.7. I say so because I was with 1.6 and this solution did not work until I swapped it to 1.7 ;)

Comment: Update Url changed, see https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools which refers to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

see on eclipse marketplace the  minimum version of Java required to run GlassFish Tools.

```
Mars - Java 8
Luna - Java 8
Kepler - Java 7
Juno - Java 6
```

- See more at: 
  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools

Comment: yes this worked for me. i tired from luna and mars firstly and after looking at this comment i installed Kepler. it worked. thanks

Answer (score -3):

Go with Eclipse Luna + RedHat JBoss WildFly 8.2, which is working just fine.

Comment: Not answering the question. Not everyone has the luxuary of choosing their environments.