# Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and glassfish tools jdk 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-luna

I cannot create new Glassfish server in Eclipse Luna.

I was able to download Glassfish tools for Eclipse Luna from the marketplace. Also I have registered Jdk 1.7 in my Installed jre's. Still I cannot view an option for glassfish server in create new server.

**Already tried:**

I have tried installing/uninstalling the the glassfish tools, restarting the eclipse. Marketplace cannot download any older version of glassfish.

Comment: I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27734022/1880810

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried earlier and now again but for some reason I cannot download the earlier versions.

Comment: Each time I try installing the plug-in through help->install new softwares it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

@unwichtich
Each time I try installing the plug-in through help->install new softwares it gives this error.

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900