# How can I launch a Glassfish server from Eclipse on OS X 10.10.3?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osx-yosemite

I was developing a website using Java EE in Eclipse and testing it locally using Glassfish, but after updating to OS X 10.10.3, the server started to timeout during launch. When trying to launch from Terminal, Glassfish failed to start, but when used with `sudo`, it started successfully. After looking around the web for a bit, I found that with 10.10.3 Glassfish required root privileges to run. Is there a way that I can make Eclipse start the server with root privileges or bypass the problem some other way?

**EDIT:** This is the log after using Siddharth's first option (the second one did not make any difference when running from Eclipse):

```
2015-05-16T16:30:39.877+1000|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-05-16T16:30:39.879+1000|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-05-16T16:30:39.980+1000|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-05-16T16:30:39.981+1000|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-05-16T16:30:39.984+1000|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-05-16T16:30:40.104+1000|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-05-16T16:30:40.130+1000|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-05-16T16:30:40.375+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 25ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-05-16T16:30:40.391+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-05-16T16:30:40.397+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-05-16T16:30:40.427+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-05-16T16:30:40.428+1000|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (1,426ms), startup services(619ms), total(2,045ms)
2015-05-16T16:30:40.602+1000|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://olivers-imac.gateway:8686/jndi/rmi://olivers-imac.gateway:8686/jmxrmi
```

Sometimes it only reaches here.

```
2015-05-16T16:30:40.602+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-05-16T16:30:40.670+1000|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@ae372b9 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@67403656.
```

Sometimes it only reaches here.

```
2015-05-16T16:30:40.904+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-05-16T16:30:41.444+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2015-05-16T16:30:41.450+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2015-05-16T16:30:41.453+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2015-05-16T16:30:41.471+1000|Info: Created virtual server server
2015-05-16T16:30:41.473+1000|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2015-05-16T16:30:41.638+1000|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2015-05-16T16:30:41.639+1000|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2015-05-16T16:30:41.927+1000|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2015-05-16T16:30:41.928+1000|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2015-05-16T16:30:41.930+1000|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2015-05-16T16:30:41.969+1000|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2015-05-16T16:30:42.155+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-05-16T16:30:42.170+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-05-16T16:30:42.172+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-05-16T16:30:43.060+1000|Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context ''
2015-05-16T16:30:43.655+1000|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-05-16T16:30:43.965+1000|Info: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
2015-05-16T16:30:43.966+1000|Info: Loading application __admingui done in 3,296 ms
```

---

**EDIT:** I have marked Siddharth's answer correct, as it helped me the most, however the problem solved itself completely only after updating to El Capitan.

Comment: I have the same problem in yosemite 10.10.3. From terminal with sudo works, but from eclipse didn't works. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gere Yeah, that's my problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue and has now been fixed ([see this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21343)). If you want to continue with the current version of Glassfish then may be you can consider a solution published [here](https://medium.com/@tk512/glassfish-4-1-won-t-start-in-yosemite-10-10-3-c843488f6e76).

Quoting the same solution below :-

> It turns out that the Glassfish team made an assumption that they
>   could use launchctl bsexec in their
>   nucleus/admin/launcher/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/admin/launcher/GFLauncher.java
>   file.
>
> This sub-command now requires root privileges.
>
> Someone has submitted a patch to Glassfish trunk, but if you want to
>   continue using Glassfish immediately, you can create this script
>   somewhere e.g. ~/bin/launchctl.
>
> ```bash
> #!/bin/bash
> # A little hack to wrap launchctl in order to
> # successfully start Glassfish on Yosemite 10.10.3+
> if [[ ${1} == "bsexec" ]]; then
>     nohup ${@:3}
> else
>     /bin/launchctl ${@}
> fi
> ```
>
> Remember to ‘chmod 755 ~/bin/launchctl’ so that it is executable.
>
> Also remember that your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile must have
>   something like this:
>
> ```bash
> export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> The idea here is that this script is a wrapper for launchctl. As a
>   user in Yosemite 10.10.3, you cannot run bsexec, but you may want to
>   use launchctl for other things.

Comment: I tried the bottom option (I was unsure of how to use the top one) and Glassfish still does not work. When launched from Terminal it prints:
`Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.\nThe server exited prematurely with exit code 1.\nBefore it died, it produced the following output:\n\nError: Could not find or load main class Workspace.GlassFish.glassfish4.glassfish.modules.glassfish.jar\n
\nCommand start-domain failed.` New lines are replaced with `\n`.

Comment: Actually, it works from Terminal after I installed a fresh copy of Glassfish, but it still doesn't work from Eclipse. It gets stuck after `Info: Loading application __admingui done in 3,808 ms`.

Comment: I managed to use the top method by downloading the source code and recompiling the GFLauncher class with the `nohup` change so that it worked without `sudo` from Terminal, but it still didn't work for Eclipse. It gets suck in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse luna Glassfish tools that I had installed from Eclipse MarketPlace, under OSX 10.9.

I ran across the post below on stack overflow and I guess, after the issue of the root access being resolved in 10.10, I believe that the proposed solution there should work for your case too, as it did for me.

Don't forget to uninstall the Glassfish Tools that you installed previously from the Marketplace!

[Installing Glassfish tools in eclipse luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730184/installing-glassfish-tools-in-eclipse-luna)